# Js countdown timer css formatting/ customization

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

Hi everyone i need help with css 
here is my js countdown timer for events however i need to make it responsive, how can i make the timer responsive. Which works across all browsers, mobile and tablet devices

JS

```
function startCountdown(dates, elem, format) {
var now = new Date(),
    index = 0,
    targetDate;
// Returns the next date a specific month/day combination occurs.
function nextDateOccurs(arr) {
    var monthNotYet = now.getMonth() < arr[0] - 1,
        dayNotYet = now.getMonth() == arr[0] - 1 && now.getDate() < arr[1];

    if (monthNotYet || dayNotYet) {
        // Date will pass within this calendar year
        return new Date(now.getFullYear(), arr[0] - 1, arr[1]);
    } else {
        // Date has already passed within this calendar year
        return new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, arr[0] - 1, arr[1]);
    }
}

// Returns the numeric argument followed by the singular
// or plural name of the item as is correct (and then
// a space character).
function formatQuantity(num, singular, plural) {
    return num + " " + (num == 1 ? singular : plural) + " ";
}

// Pick the target date that is closest.
for (var j = 0; j < dates.length; ++j) {
    if (nextDateOccurs(dates[j]) < nextDateOccurs(dates[index])) {
        index = j;
    }
}

// Make a Date object for the target date.
targetDate = nextDateOccurs(dates[index]);

// Update the countdown every second.
function updateCountdown() {
    var months = 0,
        millis, advNow, advNow1, words = "";

    // Update now with the current date and time.
    advNow1 = now = new Date();

    // Has the target date already passed?
    if (now >= targetDate) {
        millis = 0;
    } else {
        // Find the last time that is a whole number of months past now
        // but less than one month before the target date.
        while (advNow1 < targetDate) {
            ++months;
            advNow = advNow1;
            advNow1 = new Date(now);
            advNow1.setMonth(now.getMonth() + months);
        }--months;

        // Find the time difference in milliseconds within the month.
        millis = targetDate - advNow;
    }

    // Turn that into months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
    words += formatQuantity(months, "month", "months");
    words += formatQuantity(Math.floor(millis / 864e5), "day", "days");
    words += formatQuantity(Math.floor(millis % 864e5 / 36e5), "hour", "hours");

    // Update the element.
    elem.innerHTML = format.replace(/%NAME%/g, dates[index][2])
        .replace(/%WORDS%/g, words);
}
updateCountdown();
setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
}

function countdownSettings() {
startCountdown([
// Change the dates here to customize the script.
[12, 30, "Awesome Event here"],
    [2, 28, "countdown2"],
   [7, 29, "countdown3"],

    ],
/* Element to update */
document.getElementById("countdown"),
/* Format of HTML inserted */
    "%NAME% <br> <br> <br> %WORDS%");
}

// Run the script only after the page has fully loaded
// to ensure that elements are accessible from the DOM.
if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener("load", countdownSettings, false);
} else {
window.attachEvent("onload", countdownSettings);
}

countdownSettings()


WebFontConfig = {
google: {
    families: ['Open+Sans:600,800,400:latin']
}
};
(function () {
var wf = document.createElement('script');
wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
wf.type = 'text/javascript';
wf.async = 'true';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

CSS

```
#mc_embed_signup {
background:#888;
clear:left;
font:14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body {
 text-align: center;
}
p {
color: #F8F8F8;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size: 48px;
}
h1 {
color: #F8F8F8;
font-weight: semibold;
font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size: 28px;
}
h2 {
color: #000;
font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#888">
 <h2>nextcountdown</h2>

 <h1>next countdown</h1>

<p id="countdown"http://jsfiddle.net/> </p>
 <h1>Don't miss out! Get  Reminder for our awesome event</h1>
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div>
                <input type="text" name=" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: reading the comments on the html it seems that would end up in some email, that would change everything because of various mail reader support around, is this the case?

Comment: yes i removed some of the details from code, using mailchimp form here, so its really not going to affect other parts

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this out? I only added some divs and style. Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbwgjfvs/) link. I think it works.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot  for this it defiantly looks better, however i think i need to have numbers in bigger size, sorry i suck at css